# Get used CPU%, Disk% & memory % counters

Tags: windows, performance, powershell, scripting

I am trying to get these 3 counters thru PowerShell, could you help? Something like below:

```
Hostname1 : CPU% : 75%
Hostname1 : MEM% : 55%
Hostname1 : Disk1 % : 15%
Hostname1 : Disk2 % : 10%
Hostname1 : Disk3 % : 13%
Hostname1 : Disk4 % : 12%
Hostname2 : CPU% : 75%
Hostname2 : MEM% : 55%
Hostname2 : Disk1 % : 11%
Hostname2 : Disk2 % : 15%
Hostname2 : Disk3 % : 15%
```

Note: I could not find a counter for %used/memory so I am not going thru performance counters.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: nope, i do not have the code for the above trying to have one set so i can get all into one script.

Answer (score 6):

Likely your easiest method is using WMI. The below is a script I wrote up for you to demonstrate the ability.

You would need to work on the formatting and I left out disk stats - so some work required.

```
# Lets import our list of computers
$computers = get-Content .\computer-list.txt
# computer-list.txt is your hostnames each on a new line

# Lets create our variables
$HostInfo = @()

# Lets loop through our computer list from computers
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    # Lets get our stats
    # Lets create a re-usable WMI method for CPU stats
    $ProcessorStats = Get-WmiObject win32_processor -computer $computer
    $ComputerCpu = $ProcessorStats.LoadPercentage 
    # Lets create a re-usable WMI method for memory stats
    $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem -computer $computer
    # Lets grab the free memory
    $FreeMemory = $OperatingSystem.FreePhysicalMemory
    # Lets grab the total memory
    $TotalMemory = $OperatingSystem.TotalVisibleMemorySize
    # Lets do some math for percent
    $MemoryUsed = ($FreeMemory/ $TotalMemory) * 100
    $PercentMemoryUsed = "{0:N2}" -f $MemoryUsed

    # Lets throw them into an object for outputting
    $objHostInfo = New-Object System.Object
    $objHostInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $computer
    $objHostInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CPULoadPercent -Value $ComputerCpu
    $objHostInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MemoryUsedPercent -Value $PercentMemoryUsed

    # Lets dump our info into an array
    $HostInfo += $objHostInfo
}

# Lets output to the console
$HostInfo
```

Comment: Useful (as I have an extremely limited knowledge of PowerShell), however should your MemoryUsed be Memory available?

Comment: What you actually want is:

`$MemoryUsed = 100 - (($FreeMemory/ $TotalMemory) * 100)`

Comment: What you actually want is:

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$system = Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem
$totalPhysicalMem = $system.TotalVisibleMemorySize
$freePhysicalMem = $system.FreePhysicalMemory
$usedPhysicalMem = $totalPhysicalMem - $freePhysicalMem
$usedPhysicalMemPct = [math]::Round(($usedPhysicalMem / $totalPhysicalMem) * 100,1)


$driveLetters = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | select DriveLetter
foreach ($driveLetter in $driveLetters)
{
    $drive = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | where {$_.DriveLetter -eq $driveLetter.DriveLetter}
    $usedDiskSpace = $drive.Capacity - $drive.FreeSpace
    $usedDiskSpacePct = [math]::Round(($usedDiskSpace / $drive.Capacity) * 100,1)
}
```